# How do Python subshell and Linux shell produce different results?

Tags: python, linux, command, puppet, subshell

I have a folder with subfolders containing *.pp* Puppet manifest files. I found out that I can use *puppet strings* tool to convert *.pp* files into json.

This can be easily achieved using Unix terminal, running command `puppet strings generate --format json file_name.pp`.

I wrote a simple python script to iterate over all the files in the specific directory and its subdirectories and run this command on every file.

Sadly, I am getting only empty *puppet strings* template without any content when running the script, (I implemented printing out the commands that are called), however using the commands works perfectly fine inside Unix terminal.

Please, what am I doing wrong that the commands work in Unix shell but not inside Python's subshell?

Here is the code:

```
import os


def generate_json():
    for dirpath, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(
            '/home/odolezal/PycharmProjects/puppet_parser/files/'):
        for filename in [f for f in filenames if f.endswith(".pp")]:
            print(os.path.join(dirpath, filename))
            print('puppet strings generate --format json ' + filename)
            os.system('puppet strings generate --format json ' + str(filename))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    generate_json()
```

Comment: You print the absolute path `print(os.path.join(dirpath, filename))` but use only the `filename` .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer - changing the last function line to `os.system('puppet strings generate --format json ' + os.path.join(dirpath, filename))` works perfectly as I forgot the script does not change the current dir when operating on subdirectories and files inside them.